# GNU make conditional on $(MAKELEVEL) - three cases 0, 1 more

Tags: linux, gnu-make

For the [BISMON](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) open source program (near commit `18d422a495044dc07` branch `readline`, on Linux/x86-64, using [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) 4 (on Ubuntu 20 if that matters)

I am trying to handle a three case conditional on `$(MAKELEVEL)` for the cases level zero, level one, other levels and coding [this `GNUmakefile`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/readline/GNUmakefile) modified to have (near lines 125 and following)

```
ifeq ($(MAKELEVEL),0)
_bismon-config.mk _bm_config.h _bm_config.c: BISMON-config.cc
    sleep 0.05
    bash -x -c 'if [ ! -x ./BISMON-config -a "$(MAKELEVEL)" = 0 ] ; then /bin/sleep 0.1 ; $(MAKE)  ./BISMON-config ; fi'
    sleep 0.1
    $(MAKE) runconfig
    sleep 0.02

### the configurator program
BISMON-config: BISMON-config.cc __timestamp.o $(warning $(MAKE) BISMON-config at level zero)
    @echo Building BISMON-config using BISMON_SHORTGIT=$(BISMON_SHORT_GIT)
    @bash -c "if [ -f $@ ] ; then /bin/mv -v $@ $@~ ; fi"
    $(GXX) $(BM_CXX_STANDARD_FLAGS) '-DBISMON_SHORTGIT="$(BISMON_SHORT_GIT)"' -Wall -Wextra -O -g $^ -lreadline  -o $@
endif


ifeq ($(MAKELEVEL),1)
_bismon-config.mk _bm_config.h _bm_config.c: BISMON-config.cc
    sleep 0.01
    bash -x -c 'if [ ! -x ./BISMON-config -a "$(MAKELEVEL)" = 0 ] ; then /bin/sleep 0.1 ; $(MAKE)  ./BISMON-config ; fi'
    sleep 0.2
    $(MAKE) runconfig
    sleep 0.03

### the configurator program
BISMON-config: BISMON-config.cc __timestamp.o $(warning $(MAKE) BISMON-config at level one)
    @echo Building BISMON-config using BISMON_SHORTGIT=$(BISMON_SHORT_GIT) at level one
    @bash -c "if [ -f $@ ] ; then /bin/mv -v $@ $@~ ; fi"
    $(GXX) $(BM_CXX_STANDARD_FLAGS) '-DBISMON_SHORTGIT="$(BISMON_SHORT_GIT)"' -Wall -Wextra -O -g $^ -lreadline  -o $@
endif

ifeq($(findstring $(MAKELEVEL),0 1),$(strip))
else
_bismon-config.mk _bm_config.h _bm_config.c:
    sleep 0.3
    $(MAKE) runconfig
BISMON-config: $(error wrongly doing:  $(MAKE) BISMON-config at level $(MAKELEVEL))
endif
```

For some reasons, the last dozen of lines are wrong.

### What mistake am I doing?

Comment: Please describe how "the last dozeon of lines are wrong".  What happens when you try to use this?  What error or wrong result did you get (please cut and paste, don't paraphrase)?  What did you expect to happen?  Is this your _actual_ makefile?  One thing I see right off the bat is that `ifeq(...` is wrong: you must have a space after `ifeq`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `else`?

```
ifeq ($(MAKELEVEL),0)
  ...
else ifeq ($(MAKELEVEL),1)
  ...
else
  ...
endif
```

As an aside, `$(strip)` is just referencing a variable named `strip`, it's not running the function `strip` with no arguments.  So if you have a variable `strip` in your makefile this will not do what you want I assume.  If you want to compare a string to the empty value just use an empty value:

```
ifeq ($(...),)
```